# Flattening a Dictionary of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have this line of code:

```
Dictionary<string,string> alreadyThere = GetItFromFooMethod();
List<string> flatList = alreadyThere.Values.SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```

But I get this compile error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

Why does it think I need `char`? and how can I fix it?

Comment: SelectMany flattens a list of lists. A string is an array of characters.  So you're getting `List<char>` back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just want to get the `Values` like this:

```
List<string> flatList = alreadyThere.Values.ToList();
```

Since `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`, `SelectMany` returns `IEnumerable<char>`. It thinks that you are trying to get each character separately into a list. But I don't think you want that..

Flattening can be useful only if you have a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` for example if you would have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` then that code would work.But in your case the `Values` collection is already an `IEnumereable<string>`,so calling `ToList` should be enough...